# Mean of normal distribution generated using numpy.random.randn() is not '0'

Tags: python, numpy, normal-distribution, quantopian

I am trying to follow this [tutorial from quantopian](https://www.quantopian.com/lectures/instability-of-estimates) where they are trying to show that samples progressively exhibit characteristics of a normal distribution with increase in size .

I tried to generate a normal distribution using the `numpy.random.randn()` method as shown in the tutorial.

I understand that this method returns a [sample of the standard normal distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html) and that for a normal distribution, `mean = 0` and `standard deviation = 1`

***But***, when I check the mean and standard deviation of this distribution, they show weird values i.e `mean = 0.23` and `standard deviation = 0.49`.

CODE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#np.random.seed(123)
normal = np.random.randn(6)

print (normal.mean())
print (normal.std())
```

RESULT:

```
0.231567632423
0.488577812058
```

I am guessing this could be because I am looking at **just a sample and not the whole distribution** and it is not perfectly normal. But if that is the case:

1. What characteristics should I expect from this sample?
2. Isn't the tutorial's suggestion wrong, since it will never be a normal distribution?

Comment: You have a very small sample so deviations from mean = 0 and sd = 1 are expected. As you increase the sample size, the distribution will approach to a standard normal distribution.

Comment: @ayhan, I get it now.

Comment: Please post an MCVE. Don't expect people to go off site to answer you

Comment: @MadPhysicist, added code

Comment: @MadPhysicist Added code and result within question.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the reference to your screenshot as well.

Answer (score 4):

You have a sample size or 6.  It is not sufficiently large enough to get close to approximating the normal distribution.  Try it with 600 or 6000 to get a good representation of the distribution.

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(600)
x.mean(), x.std()
# returns:
(-0.07760043571247623, 0.9664411074909558)

x = np.random.randn(6000)
x.mean(), x.std()
# returns:
(0.003908119246211815, 1.0001989021750033)
```

The average roll of a 6-sided die should be 3.5.  However, if you only roll it 6 times, it is unlikely you will have an average of 3.5.